# Sum of all values within two date fields

Tags: reporting-services

I try to make a sum of all values within two date fields (StartDate and EndDat of Dataset1).

The date field are only in a different dataset then the number field (Dataset 2)

Here is an example of the data:

Dataset 1

```
Name        StartDate        EndDate   
-----------------------------------
1234        01-01-2018       31-12-2018
```

Dateset2

```
Name    Date         Weight
-----------------------------------
1234    31-12-2017   10000
1234    4-1-2018     20000
1234    8-1-2018     44000
1234    17-8-2018    50000
```

In the above example, the weight of 31-12-2017 should not be included in the sum

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
SELECT SUM(Weight) FROM Dateset2 WHERE Date >= (SELECT StartDate FROM DataSet1)
AND Date <= (SELECT EndDate FROM DataSet1)
```

Please let me know if this helps.

PS- DataSet1 contains 1 row. Else filter out data from dateset1 to 1 row

Comment: Thanks so far, I only get the following error in SSRS 

"The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox239.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected."

I want to use this expression in a table where data from dataset 1 is used. For this reason, a lookup between the name field will also have to take place?

PS. Dataset 1 contains more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include the name from Dataset 2 and add Grouping

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Weight) as Weight
FROM Dateset2 
WHERE Date >= (SELECT StartDate FROM DataSet1)
AND Date <= (SELECT EndDate FROM DataSet1)
Group By Name
```

What does the SSRS Report look like?

Comment: I want to use this expression in a table where data from dataset 1 is used. For this reason, a lookup between the name field will also have to take place?

Comment: The data that you're summing isn't in dataset one. To get the outcome that you've requested you need to sum everything in dataset two with the constraints provided in dataset one.

Other than what you've initially asked, what are you trying to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: The problem is only that sum depends on the dates from the other dataset. What I want to achieve is that the purchase obligation between 2 different dates (Dataset 1) is compared with the actual decrease (Dataset 2)